# Is a nonlinear/non-stationary mean function viable in Gaussian process?

Tags: mean, stationarity, gaussian-process

I have a Gaussian process and my input is $x=[x_1, x_2]^T$. I want to use a nonstationary mean function, such as $\mu(x) = a+bx_2$ or $\mu(x) = a+bx_2^2$ where $a, b$ are constants. My question is

1. Is this a valid mean function in Gaussian process? Or, in other words, am I able to use any kind of mean function, such as, a nonlinear nonstationary mean function?
2. Does this mean function break the basic assumption of Gaussian process? The assumption "any finite number of variables have a joint Gaussian distribution".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No

See equations (2.37) and (2.38) of [Rasmussen's book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf), which addresses this situation. If you specify a prior mean of some arbitrary $\mu\left(x\right)$, then the prior joint distribution at any two $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ is still Gaussian with
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} f\left(x_{1}\right) \\ f\left(x_{2}\right) \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} \mu\left(x_{1}\right) \\ \mu\left(x_{2}\right) \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k\left(x_{1}, x_{1}\right) & k\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \\ k\left(x_{2}, x_{1}\right) & k\left(x_{2}, x_{2}\right) \end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{equation}
where $k\left(x, x'\right)$ is your covariance function. Moreover, the posterior mean at a test point $x_{*}$ is effectively the same as subtracting the prior mean $\mu\left(x\right)$ from each target $y$, performing zero-mean-prior Gaussian process on that dataset, and then adding the mean $\mu\left(x_{*}\right)$ back to it; this is the essence of equation (2.38).

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, both mean and covariance can be any kind of functions. Is that correct? thanks.

Comment: Mean - yes, covariance - no. The covariance function needs to satisfy some certain properties, but a list of valid covariance functions can easily be found online or in a textbook.